# Remover linhas com uma condição em um Dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

Gostaria de saber como excluir as linhas baseado na coluna `cliente_id` segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: Tabela de exemplo]

O Objetivo é deletar as linhas onde `cliente_id` aparece somente uma vez que nesse caso seria o ID 4 e o 5, deixando o restante

Comment: Outra solução seria filtrar os indices dos elementos que não se repetem e então remover linhas baseadas nesses indices. Esse exemplo é bastante específico ao seu problema: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/dropunique#main.py Para a finalidade aqui do site a [resposta do Paulo Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/572990/137387) é mais adequada pois é flexível e permite que outros usuários a reaproveitem aplicando diferentes condições de remoção.

Comment: PS: Quando fizer uma pergunta sobre dataframes ao menos deixe na pergunta um código no formato texto que crie o df de amostra para que as pessoas possam apenas copiar e colar. Toma muito tempo copiar os dados individualmente de uma imagem para então montar o df para então analisar o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é usar o [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
# contando items
contagem = df["cliente_id"].value_counts()

# condição para que a contagem seja maior que 1
condicao = contagem.gt(1)

# criando novo df com clientes que apareçam mais de uma vez
novo_df = df[df["cliente_id"].isin(contagem.index[condicao])]
```

Veja como isto acontece, passo a passo:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({"cliente_id": [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   cliente_id
0           1
1           2
2           3
3           4
4           5
5           1
6           2
7           4
8           5

In [3]: contagem = df["cliente_id"].value_counts()

In [4]: contagem
Out[4]:
1    2
2    2
4    2
5    2
3    1
Name: cliente_id, dtype: int64

In [5]: condicao = contagem.gt(1)

In [6]: condicao
Out[6]:
1     True
2     True
4     True
5     True
3    False
Name: cliente_id, dtype: bool

In [7]: novo_df = df[df["cliente_id"].isin(contagem.index[condicao])]

In [8]: novo_df
Out[8]:
   cliente_id
0           1
1           2
3           4
4           5
5           1
6           2
7           4
8           5

In [9]:
```

Perceba que o `cliente_id = 3` não está no `novo_df`.